# Summarize values by group, but keep original data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to figure out how to sum `values` belonging to `category` a and b by factor `file`, but also keep the original data.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, values = runif(20), category = rep(letters[1:5], 4), file = as.factor(sort(rep(1:5, 4)))) 


   ID     values category file
1   1 0.65699229        a    1
2   2 0.70506478        b    1
3   3 0.45774178        c    1
4   4 0.71911225        d    1
5   5 0.93467225        e    1
6   6 0.25542882        a    2
7   7 0.46229282        b    2
8   8 0.94001452        c    2
9   9 0.97822643        d    2
10 10 0.11748736        e    2
11 11 0.47499708        a    3
12 12 0.56033275        b    3
13 13 0.90403139        c    3
14 14 0.13871017        d    3
15 15 0.98889173        e    3
16 16 0.94666823        a    4
17 17 0.08243756        b    4
18 18 0.51421178        c    4
19 19 0.39020347        d    4
20 20 0.90573813        e    4
```

so that

- `df[1,2]` will be added to `df[2,2]` to category `'ab'` for file 1
- `df[6,2]` will be added to `df[7,2]` to category `'ab'`  for file 2
- etc.

So far I have this:

```
df %>% 
    filter(category %in% c('a' , 'b')) %>%
    group_by(file) %>% 
    summarise(values = sum(values))
```

## Problem

I would like to change the category of the summed values to "ab" and append it to the original data frame in the same pipeline.

**Desired output**:

```
   ID     values category file
1   1 0.65699229        a    1
2   2 0.70506478        b    1
3   3 0.45774178        c    1
4   4 0.71911225        d    1
5   5 0.93467225        e    1
6   6 0.25542882        a    2
7   7 0.46229282        b    2
8   8 0.94001452        c    2
9   9 0.97822643        d    2
10 10 0.11748736        e    2
11 11 0.47499708        a    3
12 12 0.56033275        b    3
13 13 0.90403139        c    3
14 14 0.13871017        d    3
15 15 0.98889173        e    3
16 16 0.94666823        a    4
17 17 0.08243756        b    4
18 18 0.51421178        c    4
19 19 0.39020347        d    4
20 20 0.90573813        e    4
21 21 1.25486225       ab    1
22 22 1.87216325       ab    2
23 23 1.36548126       ab    3
```

Comment: Maybe setDT(df)[category %chin% c(‘a’,’b’), summed:=sum(values), file]

Comment: @chinsoon12 `%chin%` actually won't work here (assuming default stringsAsFactor option) because category is a factor and not character. You should post this as an answer though

Comment: Commented from a phone and Didn’t test so better not post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the result

```
df %>% bind_rows(
  df %>% 
    filter(category %in% c('a' , 'b')) %>%
    group_by(file) %>% 
    mutate(values = sum(values), category = paste0(category,collapse='')) %>% 
    filter(row_number() == 1 & n() > 1)
) %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
```

BTW the code pro produce the dataframe in the example is this one:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:20, values = runif(20), category = rep(letters[1:5], 4), file = as.factor(sort(rep(1:4, 5))))
```

now lets say you want to sum multiple columns, you need to provide the list in a vector:

```
cols = c("values") # columns to be sum

df %>% bind_rows(
  df %>% 
    filter(category %in% c('a' , 'b')) %>%
    group_by(file) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(cols), sum) %>% 
    mutate(category = paste0(category,collapse='')) %>% 
    filter(row_number() == 1 & n() > 1)
) %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
```

Comment: plus 1 for the automatic new name creation by paste collapse

Comment: would you know how to do the summation if you would want to do it for a whole set of columns? My real data has 80 parameter columns. For the moment I just needed values from 2 columns, which is manageable by hand, but I would like to make the code work for a flexibel nr of columns in automated way

Comment: Edited the code so you can provide a vector of columns you want to sum

Comment: ok, managed to make code that allows for calculating the new total, min, and max of the merged data sets (clusters in multivariate analyses). Now trying to figure out how to recalculate the mean properly. Posting a new question for this

Comment: share the link ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972840/recalculate-the-new-weighted-mean-when-merging-two-factors-by-group-and-keep-or

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(category %in% c('a' , 'b')) %>%
  group_by(file) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(category) > 1) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(values)) %>%
  mutate(category="ab",
         ID=max(df1$ID)+1:n())  %>% 
  bind_rows(df1, .)
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding factor and character vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#>    ID     values category file
#> 1   1 0.62585921        a    1
#> 2   2 0.61865851        b    1
#> 3   3 0.05274456        c    1
#> 4   4 0.68156961        d    1
.
.
.
#> 19 19 0.43239411        d    5
#> 20 20 0.85886314        e    5
#> 21 21 1.24451773       ab    1
#> 22 22 0.99001810       ab    2
#> 23 23 1.25331943       ab    3
```

Answer (score 1):

This `data.table` approach uses a self-join to get all of the possible two-character combinations.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df_self_join <- df[df, on = .(file), allow.cartesian = T
                   ][category != i.category,
                     .(category = paste0(i.category, category), values = values + i.values, file)
                     ][order(category), .(ID = .I + nrow(df), values, category, file)]

rbindlist(list(df, df_self_join))

    ID     values category file
 1:  1 0.76984382        a    1
 2:  2 0.54311583        b    1
 3:  3 0.23462016        c    1
 4:  4 0.60179043        d    1
...
20: 20 0.03534223        e    5
21: 21 1.31295965       ab    1
22: 22 0.51666175       ab    2
23: 23 1.02305754       ab    3
24: 24 1.00446399       ac    1
25: 25 0.96910373       ac    2
26: 26 0.87795389       ac    4
#total of 80 rows
```

Here is pretty close `dplyr` translation:

```
library(dplyr)
tib <- as_tibble(df)

inner_join(tib, tib, by = 'file')%>%
  filter(ID.x != ID.y)%>%
  transmute(category = paste0(category.x, category.y)
            , values = values.x + values.y
            , file)%>%
  arrange(category)%>%
  bind_rows(tib, .)%>%
  mutate(ID = row_number())%>%
  filter(category == 'ab') #filter added to show the "ab" files

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID values category file 
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>    <fct>
1    21  1.31  ab       1    
2    22  0.517 ab       2    
3    23  1.02  ab       3
```